# jquery how to return list of error fields?

Tags: jquery, alert, each, jquery-validation-engine

Im using the validationEngine and having trouble with alerting the list of names of error fields after submitting the form.

What Ive got is:

```
$('#borrow-form').live('jqv.field.result',function(event, field, errorFound, prompText){

    if(errorFound){
        field.addClass('error');

    } else if(field.hasClass('error')){
        field.removeClass('error');
    }


    field.each(function(){
        var show = $(this).attr("name");
        alert(show);
    });



});
```

After submitting the form, the browser is displaying multiple alerts - one after another.

The addClass/removeClass for everyfield works fine, but the alerting is not.

How can I list **all errors in one alert** ?

I need exactly same list as here: https://form.paydayrocket.com/page2/ - please click on the submit button without filling anything.

Comment: you keep requesting other people to do your code and keep telling them to make changes to their code, so that you don't have to understand the code and simply copy and paste it.

Comment: Mate please dont be mad! Im not a jquery pro, I've tried to resolve my issue since 3 days and without success. I dont see any contribution from you to help me so dont really know why you have problem? No offence!

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array and add each name value when you iterate through your each-method:

```
var names = new Array();

var counter = 0;

field.each(function(){
    var show = $(this).attr("name");
    names[counter] = show;
    counter = counter++;
}
```

Afterwards, you can construct a string that contains all the names with line breaks, or simply print out the array.

```
var printMe = '';
for (var i in names){
    printMe = printMe + names[i] + '\n';
}

alert(printMe);
```

Comment: weird thing, it still displays one alert after one alert instead of one long alert with list of errors. is it because i have this whole code in $("#borrow-form").live function?

Comment: Try writing alert(counter) in the field.each method, then you can check. If it alerts you with a bunch of 0-messages, all of the code is run for each time. If it alerts you with 0, 1, 2 and so on, the code should be correct and something else is wrong.

Comment: Is it only erroneous fields that are alerted, or do all of your fields send an alert?

Comment: It was alerting all fields, not only the invalid. I used the hooks from validationEngine and binded the form to jqv.form.result and then was trying to get for each errorFound the field name by selecting the fields which has class ".error" - vE adds that class but then the browser was saying the field.each is not a function - dunno really why because i set the var field = $(".error"), tried even to do it like this: $(".error").each(function.. but same bad result. I gaved up with this list of errors and Im now printing simple alert with few instructions for end user. Thanks for you help anyways!